# Ошибка: Read-only file system

Tags: android

Здравствуйте из-за чего может быть данная ошибка. В результате чего приложение не запускается.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.EdwardSark.cutoutascene/com.EdwardSark.cutoutascene.MainMenu}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /INSTALLATION (Read-only file system)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1734)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1753)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:999)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3820)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /INSTALLATION (Read-only file system)
at net.robotmedia.billing.utils.Installation.id(Installation.java:39)
at net.robotmedia.billing.utils.Security.getObfuscator(Security.java:57)
at net.robotmedia.billing.utils.Security.obfuscate(Security.java:49)
at net.robotmedia.billing.BillingController.isPurchased(BillingController.java:287)
at com.EdwardSark.cutoutascene.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:72)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1698)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /INSTALLATION (Read-only file system)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:263)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:125)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:97)
at net.robotmedia.billing.utils.Installation.writeInstallationFile(Installation.java:54)
at net.robotmedia.billing.utils.Installation.id(Installation.java:35)
```

Comment: вроде ясно написало, что "FileNotFoundException" - не нашло оно файла `/INSTALLATION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь создать файл в корне ФС, на что у вас, естественно, не хватит прав.

*UPD*: Посмотрел на используемую вами библиотеку, точнее, [на место, где происходит исключение](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/blob/master/AndroidBillingLibrary/src/net/robotmedia/billing/utils/Installation.java#L54) (обратите внимание ещё на [вот эту строчку](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/blob/master/AndroidBillingLibrary/src/net/robotmedia/billing/utils/Installation.java#L32)). Судя по симптомам и коду, вы столкнулись с известным багом, описанным [здесь](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8886).

Comment: Я так понимаю это связано с billing библиотекой?

Comment: Судя по стэктрэйсу — да.